# How can I show a dialog box like stackoverflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code on my page:

```
$('#Report').click(Report);

    function Report() {
        var e = encodeURIComponent,
                arr = [
                "dataSource=" + e($('#DataSource').val()),
                "statusID=" + e($('#StatusID').val())
                ];
        window.location.href = '/Administration/Tests/Report?' + arr.join("&");
        return false;
    }
```

When a user clicks on the button with Id=Report then the function is called and it shows a page with report information.

However if the dataSource and statusID are not set then my code ends in an exception.

Is there some way I can check for the value of DataSource not being equal to "00" and StatusID not being equal to "0" and then show a dialog box telling the user these fields should be selected.

Ideally I would like to have something like the dialog box that Stackoverflow uses.

Comment: Which stackoverflow dialog od you have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what `00` and `0` represent in your request, but I put them in there. I'm not familiar with that Stack Overflow dialog box, but here is some starting code to play with. The outer div (`#error-frame`) prevents clicking on any other elements while the box is displayed.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/CW5wW/

Script:

```
function Report() {

    var dataSource = $('#DataSource').val(),
        statusId = $('#StatusID').val();

    if( dataSource && statusId && dataSource != '00' && statusId != '0' ) {

        var e = encodeURIComponent,
            arr = [
            "dataSource=" + e(dataSource),
            "statusID=" + e(statusId)
            ];

        window.location.href = '/Administration/Tests/Report?' + arr.join("&");

    } else {
        //error msg here, perhaps:
        showError( 'Both Data Source and Status ID are required.' );
    };

    return false;

}

function showError( message ) {

    document.getElementById( 'error-message' ).textContent = message;
    document.getElementById( 'error-frame' ).style.display = 'block';    

    var error = document.getElementById( 'error' );

    error.style.left = ( ( window.innerWidth / 2 ) - ( error.scrollWidth / 2 ) ) + 'px';
    error.style.top = ( ( window.innerHeight / 2 ) - ( error.scrollHeight / 2 ) ) + 'px';

};
```

HTML:

```
<div id="error-frame"><div id="error"><div id="error-message"></div><button onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display='none'">OK</button></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#error-frame {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#error {
    border: 4px solid darkgray;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
vwidth: 200px;
}

#error button {
    position: absolute;    
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: The dialog box I was thinking about was the one that appears center screen with the thick gray border around it. I just tried a few different things and could not get this kind of box to appear. I think it's the one that appears if I try to ask too many questions in a day or try to ask questions too often.

Comment: I added a snippet to play with for the dialog box.